# Github code search on any branch

Tags: github

It is against general git workflow to make feature changes on a master branch. Sow= if I were to fork a repo my work ends up in .. feature branches..

How can I search those non-master branches on github?

Actually - even advanced search on Github seems to not find much of anything except for repository names and README files. It is not searching the codebase??

Here is an example of searching the `yahoo` user account for `Process`

[image]

: that should come up with dozens if not hundreds of hits. But we get .. *four* hits ..

[image]

So in general the github code search is a bit of a mystery .  I really want to find certain code snippets .. either on master or another branch .. is there a way to do this??

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are tabs just below the header of the page - Repositories, Code, Commits, etc. If I click the Code tab I get 2k+ results.

There are some restrictions with searching code on GitHub, however, **and branches other than `master` are not considered in the search**. Also, only files smaller than 384 KB and repositories with less than 500,000 files are searchable. You can find more information related to searching code on GitHub here: https://help.github.com/articles/searching-code/

Comment: I've +1'ed this for pointing out exactly where is located the utter fail in the stupid Github advanced search results page, which almost invariably returns "We couldn't find any repositories matching ...." when the the search term itself makes it clear that we're looking for code, in a repository, and "no repos found" is non-responsive answer.  Grrrr. But thanks.